# Prove by deduction $\displaystyle \frac{a^2 + b^2}{2} \geq ab$

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

I am currently working in the following question:

> Prove by deduction $$\frac{a^2 + b^2}{2} \geq ab$$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

My question is: can prove instead the following?

$$\frac{a^2 + b^2}{2} - ab \geq 0$$

**My solution:**

$$\frac{a^2 + b^2}{2} - ab = \frac{a^2 + b^2 -2ab}{2} = \frac{(a-b)^2}{2} \geq 0$$

Comment: That’s correct (because the square of real numbers is always never a negative number)!

Comment: What's the alternative to proving it by deduction?

Comment: Perfectly correct.  And note that your argument also shows that you only get equality when $a=b$.

Comment: this is just AM-GM

Comment: we can prove this also by jensen to log x

Answer (score 1):

You are correct since $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}-ab\geq 0\iff\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\geq ab.$$

Alternatively since $(a-b)^2\geq0$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$ we have $$a^2+b^2\geq2ab$$ or $$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\geq ab$$
as required.

Comment: +1. I was thinking that the start is more simple considering $(a-b)^2\geq0$.